# How do I get Identity Server 4 to run over HTTPS on my local machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have created an Identity Server 4 project from the `is4aspid` project template as follows:

`dotnet new is4aspid -n IdentityProvider`

Now when I debug this project it defaults to an unsecured HTTP connection. How do I get it to run using HTTPS instead?

I have tried adding https to the the startup `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` and changing the launchsettings.json to default to https://localhost:5000 but this had no effect. When I manually navigate to https://localhost:5000 an error page is shown with `Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`.

The documentation [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/index.html) doesn't seem to have any information regarding this and is ironically enough operating over an unsecured connection. This is starting make me think that Identity Server is meant to be run over an unsecured conenction.

Comment: Services that operate over http don't really have to care about the security of the connection because it isn't their job to set it up; it's the web server that does it. By the time the service sees the data, it doesn't know whether it arrived by http or ssl over http. Look into how to make *any* website use https in the web server you're using for id4 (kestrel?)

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I see, it seems like I hae a fundamental misunderstanding over how this is supposed to work. Thank you for the link, I will look into this.

Comment: First, this issue not related with IdentityServer. I think, you in Linux. You have to use additional front-end such like nginx for receving inbound connections. And attach the ASP.NET Core as a back-end with reverse proxy strategy. The ASP.NET Core has Kestrel for listening HTTP connections but it has not designed for public service.

Comment: I usually start with the dotnet new is4empty and then the is4ui template. I would skip is4aspid if you don't actually have a good reason to add ASP.NET Identity